# 7 bit Address of different devices for I²C communication

Tags: i2c

Please tell me how we can find the address of different devices while doing I²C (inter-integrated circuit) communication.

Answer (score 4):

Read the datasheet?  Or if you have an existing system and you're trying to probe the I2C bus to see what's on it, you could attempt a 1 byte read of all possible 128 addresses and see which ones respond with ACKs.